# How to set up a UITableViewCell style doing UITableViewController programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating UITableViewController without a help from the Storyboard.

I've got the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.cellReuseIdentifier = @"myViewControllerCellReuseIdentifier";
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:self.cellReuseIdentifier];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:self.cellReuseIdentifier];
    }
}
```

In this case the cell style is not there. How do I fix that?

Answer (score -1):

I think if you just add the UITableView, set your viewcontroller as the delegate and datasource and that's enough. If you set a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath, does it trigger?

Not sure what you're doing with,

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:self.cellReuseIdentifier];
```

Rather do this,

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

Let me know if that's not what you're looking for, good luck.

Comment: Yes, everything triggers and populates with data. I pass a right style when I initialize (and then push) an object from my `UITableViewController`'s class implementation (provided above). I do get then the right style for its `UITableView`, but I'm not getting a right style for the cell (`UITableViewCell`).

Comment: Your code looks okay for initialising the cell, do you return the cell in cellForRowAtIndex?